# ADSL device providing No NAT DMZ alongside NAT (IPv4)

Tags: networking, nat, nmap

I have an ADSL modem/router/switch which performs NAT. It does this even for the one host it can be configured to provide a DMZ.

I want to be able to perform Nmap scans from a specific host and there should be no NAT taking place for that host. One of the things that I can't currently do from behind NAT is `nmap --traceroute` with anything other than ICMP. At the same time I want the other hosts on my network to be behind NAT. My ISP assigns me a single IPv4 address, but I believe, as a business customer, that I can request an additional address.

Is is technically possible for a device to provide this sort of functionality? Is there a class of device that provides it?

**Extra: Why doesn't nmap --traceroute work**

The following works as expected:-

```
nmap -sP -PE --traceroute scanme.nmap.org

TRACEROUTE (using proto 1/icmp)
HOP RTT       ADDRESS
1   16.00 ms  my.router (192.168.1.1)
2   55.00 ms  lo0.10.central10.ptn-bng01.plus.net (195.166.128.228)
3   42.00 ms  irb.10.ptw-cr02.plus.net (84.93.249.2)
4   37.00 ms  10gigabitethernet5-1.core1.lon1.he.net (5.57.80.128)
5   33.00 ms  10ge3-1.core1.lon2.he.net (72.52.92.222)
6   100.00 ms 100ge1-1.core1.nyc4.he.net (72.52.92.166)
7   183.00 ms 10ge9-7.core1.sjc2.he.net (184.105.213.197)
8   179.00 ms 10ge3-2.core3.fmt2.he.net (184.105.222.13)
9   176.00 ms router3-fmt.linode.com (65.49.10.218)
10  168.00 ms scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.58 seconds
```

This does not work as expected:-

```
nmap -sP -PS80 --traceroute scanme.nmap.org

TRACEROUTE (using port 80/tcp)
HOP RTT       ADDRESS
1   ... 9
10  166.00 ms scanme.nmap.org (74.207.244.221)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.15 seconds
```

My understanding of this is that my.router drops the ICMP Time Exceeded messages coming from the intermediate hops and I think that's because my.router is expecting TCP responses to the TCP entries in its NAT table and considers ICMP responses to be invalid.

(I [asked the original version of this question in Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7598/5425) and was advised to ask it here)

Comment: If you have a static, 1:1 nat translation between public and private IP addresses, `nmap --traceroute` should not be a problem.  I don't really think NAT is the issue here; it sounds like the problem is PAT overload.  More basic than all that though... what are you hoping to accomplish?  Solve the `nmap` problem, or ask a theoretical question?  It seems that the "theoretical: does this device exist" portion of the question is irrelevant if you can solve the `nmap` problem... no?

Comment: I think my (two-part) question is a concrete one though I appreciate that it may seem a little confused. I want to know if a device can provide NAT to a private network of hosts whilst at the same time exposing a host to the internet without NAT; and if so, what kind of device can provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 NAT (SNAT/MASQUERADE, to be precise) cannot be turned of in gateway mode. It’s the basic mode of operation of a consumer-grade internet gateway device.

You’ll have to switch to bridged mode—if possible—and use PPPoE dialup from a host of your choice. That way, the selected host (and only this host) will have unfiltered internet access.

You won’t get an additional address, that’s usually a feature of business contracts. Your router probably can’t handle it anyway.

The host called DMZ is actually the “exposed host”. It’s basically forwarding all incoming ports to this host. Naturally, this is not actually a DMZ.